# Rails & Heroku: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app hosted on Heroku. I have some page specific Javascript that I don't want to include in my Application.js, so I've included it in my view like so:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'maps/search.js', :type => "text/javascript" %>  
<% end %>
```

And in my layout before :

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

maps/search.js has no script tags or anything, just gets right into defining functions.

Works fine locally, but live I get the below error and script doesn't execute:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

I've checked the headers and the script is indeed being transferred as text/html. I understand that I need to change that, but have no idea how to do it in Rails or Heroku, with my current setup.

Comment: add this line `config.assets.precompile += %w(search.js)` in your application.rb file and try. i hope this will work

Comment: Same error unfortunately :(

Comment: please try this once `config.assets.precompile = ['*.js']`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `, :type => "text/javascript"`

According to the docs, it does not take a type.

Comment: That's true, I only added it while troubleshooting as an extra precaution